# Change data from MSSQL depending of the selected option in html

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I have a table which is populated with some data fetched from a table in a MSSQL DB.

In this table, I have a column called `Server` that can be `1` or `2`.

```
public function getDonationsLogs() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.logs WHERE Server = 1";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    
    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

In this case I fetch the data that has the `Server` value of `1` using PHP and PDO.

What I want to do, is have a select option in HTML that can change from `1` to `2` and show the corresponding data.

Comment: You can use  this sql `WHERE Server BETWEEN 1 AND 2;` or using this `WHERE Server IN (1, 2);` both cases return `array` so you can fetch that in option fields. Good luck.

Comment: To show corresponding data you have to use `Ajax` to check  on select change event.

Comment: And how can I use Ajax for something like this? Could you link me to a tutorial or something? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Here is just first link from the search results "dependent dropdown list using jquery Ajax" : https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-how-to-make-dependent-dropdown-list-using-jquery-ajaxexample.html